# How to avoid stop in debug mode without any break point in class?

Tags: debugging, netbeans-8

Every time I start the server in debug mode it stops on the class Class.java, but it is any breakpoint there.

How can I remove this stop point?

[image]

MSC says Thread suspended by debugger
State in VM: Running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a break point in another class as class breakpoint that provoke to stop in Class.java.

[image]